# Как проверить время работы программы?

Tags: java

Собственно сабж. Но вариант:

```
st = System.nanoTime();
//что-то делаю
end = System.nanoTime();
```

не подходит, т.к выдает время после завершения всех методов. Мне нужно чтобы с момента старта программы засечь, допустим, 1 минуту, если программа выполняется больше, то принудительно выйти, вне зависимости от завершения методов. Может как-то засечь время выполнения главного потока?

Comment: Используйте ScheduledExecutorService, в нем запускайте логику с необходимой задержкой.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить отдельным тредом задачу. А потом вызовите метод get() с таймаутом.

Comment: Как здесь, например: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16277191/executor-service-timeout-of-thread

Comment: Вот ещё пример: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread

Основная конструкция для гкугления: `future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`

Comment: Обязательно почитайте Шипилёва, чем плох nanoTime - http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/ и самопальные бенчмарки вообще https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzEUyqg3WPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, можете воспользоваться способом с `System.currentTimeMills()`:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = start + 60*1000; // 60 секунд* 1000 мс/сек
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
    // work hard, play hard
}
```

[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252187/how-to-stop-execution-after-a-certain-time-in-java)

---

Можно выйти из программы из другого `Thread`:

```
public class ExitAfterMinute {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000); // минута в милисекундах
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }).start();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("I'm doing something");
        }
    }
}
```

---

Либо с помощью таймера:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimedExit {
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask exitApp = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    };

    public TimedExit() {
        timer.schedule(exitApp, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 1000));
    }
}
```

[Источник.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747277/how-to-make-java-program-exit-after-a-couple-of-seconds)

Comment: Похоже, что тело сможет занять больше минуты времени. Но не будет прервано.

Comment: @DimXenon да, верно, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Смотри, если использовать способ с потоком, то в цикле while (true) {
            System.out.println("I'm doing something");
        }                                                                                                                               будет что-то выполнятся на протяжении одной минуты, т.е. получается если я оотуда вызову несколько методов, и они закончат свою работу меньше, чем за одну минуту, то они опять же будут вызваны повторно, т.к. цикл бесконечный? Мне ж надо, чтобы они один раз выполнились и все, если успели за время 1 минуту

Comment: @R.Skidan в таком случае можно флаг поставить на выполнение - выполнилось, `int flag` сделали равным 1. В цикл входить, если `flag == 0`.

Comment: не пойму вообще смысл цикла. Можно же так сделать?                              
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000); 
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }System.out.printf("не успел");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }).start();
        //делаю мир лучше. когда сделал и успел < чем за 1 минуту, завершить - System.exit(0);
    }

Comment: @R.Skidan зачем вы делаете 2 раза выход `System.exit(0)`? Цикл `while(true)` там лишь для наглядности примера, естественно там можно без цикла, это лишь пример.

Comment: В первом случае в System.exit(0) - завершит программу, если пройдет более 1 минуты, во втором если все действия успеют выполнится меньше чем за 1 минуту. Ведь если в о втором случае System.exit(0) не ставить, программа будет ждать пока завершится Thread.sleep(60000) или я не прав?

Comment: @R.Skidan если рассуждать таким образом, то да, все верно. В вашем вопросе не стоял такой нюанс, как выход из приложения, поэтому я обратил на него внимание. P.S. если вам был дан правильный ответ - отметьте его галочкой для тех, кто в дальнейшем посетит данный топик.